# Animating & overlaying multiple plots with plotly

Tags: python, animation, plotly

I have a scatter plot & density contour and they are both animated to visualise the input dataframe as it it transitions through steps. I am trying to layer both plots on top of each other.

```
scatter_fig = px.scatter(
        history_df,
        x='x',
        y='y',
        animation_frame="step",
        animation_group="entity_id",
        range_x=(0.0, 1.0),
        range_y=(0.0, 1.0),
        hover_data=hover_data,
        render_mode="webgl" if webgl else "svg",
        **color_kwargs
    )
contour_fig = px.density_contour(
        history_df,
        x='x',
        y='y',
        animation_frame="step",
        animation_group="entity_id",
        range_x=(0.0, 1.0),
        range_y=(0.0, 1.0),
        hover_data=None
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

- you did not provide sample data so I have simulated it
- concept is very simple,  take two **plotly express** figures and frames / traces and integrate them using **graph objects**
- increased animation time as contour plot does not redraw in 500ms

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# build sample data and define required variables
history_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100),
        "y": np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100),
        "entity_id": np.random.choice(list("abcd"), 100),
    }
)
history_df = (
    history_df.groupby("entity_id", as_index=False)
    .apply(lambda d: d.reset_index(drop=True).assign(step=lambda dd: dd.index // 5))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .assign(step=lambda d: "step " + d["step"].astype(str))
)
hover_data = ["x", "y"]
webgl = None
color_kwargs = {}

# original code
scatter_fig = px.scatter(
    history_df,
    x="x",
    y="y",
    animation_frame="step",
    animation_group="entity_id",
    range_x=(0.0, 1.0),
    range_y=(0.0, 1.0),
    hover_data=hover_data,
    render_mode="webgl" if webgl else "svg",
    **color_kwargs
)
contour_fig = px.density_contour(
    history_df,
    x="x",
    y="y",
    animation_frame="step",
    animation_group="entity_id",
    range_x=(0.0, 1.0),
    range_y=(0.0, 1.0),
    hover_data=None,
)

# build frames to be animated from two source figures.  Each frame has 2 traces
frames = [
    go.Frame(data=f.data + scatter_fig.frames[i].data, name=f.name)
    for i, f in enumerate(contour_fig.frames)
]

# increase duration as contour takes a while to redraw
# increase duration as contour takes a while to redraw
updmenus = [{"args": [None, {"frame": {"duration": 2000}}],"label": "&#9654;","method": "animate",},
            {'args': [[None], {'frame': {'duration': 0}, 'mode': 'immediate', 'fromcurrent': True, }],
                  'label': '&#9724;', 'method': 'animate'} ]

# now can animate...
go.Figure(data=frames[0].data, frames=frames, layout=contour_fig.layout).update_layout(
    updatemenus=[{"buttons":updmenus}]
)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected, but in your solution the pause button no longer works. How can I fix that?

Comment: oops - skipped a couple of **updatemenus** parameters.  updated and fixed

Comment: What if I want both of them to have different color?

Comment: @Epsi95 just set `color_discrete_sequence=["red"]` or whatever you want on either or both of the **px** initial figure creation calls.  really goes with simplicity of concept, create then integrate