# Problem with animation of multiple traces with plotly

Tags: python, animation, plotly-python

I'm trying to animate multiple tracks with Python plotly.
The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
df = pd.read_csv("orbite.csv")
fig=px.scatter(df,x="X1",y="Y1",animation_frame="time",range_x=[-6,1],range_y=[-5,2])\

fig.add_scatter(df,x="X2",y="Y2",animation_frame="time",range_x=[-6,1],range_y=[-5,2])

fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]["frame"]["duration"] = 20
fig.update_layout(transition = {"duration": 20})
fig.show()
```

This is the data file:

```
      time         X1         Y1        X2         Y2
0        1  -0.001000   0.000000  0.000000  10.000000

1        2  -0.001000   0.000000 -0.035000   9.940000

2        3  -0.000951   0.000049 -0.070000   9.890000

3        4  -0.000853   0.000148 -0.105000   9.830000

4        5  -0.000707   0.000297 -0.140000   9.780000
```

The program works fine with only one animation, but if I add `fig.add_scatter()`, I get the error:

```
The 'alignmentgroup' property is a string and must be specified as:
  - A string
  - A number that will be converted to a string
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_scatter` is not using the same functionality as px.scatter (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67529369/9501624), and hence cannot be used to "combine animations".

The only way I know of is to "rebuild" the frames in a new figure based on [graph_objects and frames](https://plotly.com/python/animations/#frames) (see e.g. [Animating & overlaying multiple plots with plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68734106/animating-overlaying-multiple-plots-with-plotly)):

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from plotly import graph_objects as go

data = {
    "time": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "X1": [0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1],
    "Y1": [0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1],
    "X2": [-0.5, -0.4, -0.3, -0.2, -0.1],
    "Y2": [-0.5, -0.4, -0.3, -0.2, -0.1],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
fig1 = px.scatter(df, x="X1", y="Y1", animation_frame="time")
fig2 = px.scatter(df, x="X2", y="Y2", animation_frame="time")

# build frames to be animated from two source figures.
frames = [
    go.Frame(data=f.data + fig1.frames[i].data, name=f.name)
    for i, f in enumerate(fig2.frames)
]

combined_fig = go.Figure(data=frames[0].data, frames=frames, layout=fig1.layout)
combined_fig.show()
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the checkmark next to it, indicating that you received an answer that worked you.